# How can I unrigerster the listener to read event every 5 seconds

Tags: android, sensors

I am trying to send data of the magnetic field sensor to the Server every 5 seconds but I am facing Problem to unregister the sensorListerner from reading  data. I have tried it like this `sensorManager.registerListener(this,
sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),1000 * 10);` too but without seccuss. Currently the data are being sent to the Server 12 time in one second.

I appreciate any help.

**Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        SensorEventListener {
    String telsaString;

    private TextView magneticX;
    private TextView magneticY;
    private TextView magneticZ;
    private TextView magneticT;
    private SensorManager sensorManager = null;
    private float magX;
    private float magY;
    private float magZ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        // Capture magnetic sensor related view elements
        magneticX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valMag_X);
        magneticY = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valMag_Y);
        magneticZ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valMag_Z);
        magneticT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valMag_T);

        // Register magnetic sensor
         sensorManager.registerListener(this,
         sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
         SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);


           final SensorEventListener listener = this;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sensorManager.unregisterListener(listener);
                }
            }, 5000);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // Unregister the listener
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Unregister the listener
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {


                magX = sensorEvent.values[0];

                magY = sensorEvent.values[1];

                magZ = sensorEvent.values[2];

                magneticX.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[0]));
                magneticY.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[1]));
                magneticZ.setText(Float.toString(sensorEvent.values[2]));

                double teslaXYZ = (Math.sqrt((magX * magX) + (magY * magY)
                        + (magZ * magZ)));
                magneticT.setText(Double.toString(teslaXYZ));

                try {
                    JSONObject tesla = new JSONObject();
                    tesla.put("tesla", teslaXYZ);
                    telsaString = tesla.toString();
                    new MyAsyncTask().execute(telsaString);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
                10*1000*1000);
.
.
.
.

            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 10000) {

                lastUpdate = curTime;
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rate you provided `1000 * 10` is in microseconds, so *you are requesting a 10 millisecond update period*. Note that the requested sample period is only a request. *The rate may be faster or slower*, you need to track the times and do the appropriate thing. When you wish to completely stop receiving events, unregister your listener with the `SensorManager.unregisterListener()` method.

Comment: Cant I use Handler with postDelay of 10 seconds to reach that?

Comment: No, that will just delay the delivery of each event by 10 seconds. You have to determine if the events are coming at the right rate and handle it. Also, if you leave the sample rate high, you are burning battery unnecessarily.

Comment: And how to configure the rate? Please can you take a look at my edit code and let me know if it is not.

Comment: also when I commented the time tracking part it is too fast also I think this line here does not make sense `sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
                10*1000*1000);` ??

Comment: It's tough to determine what your edit is relative to the first code and what you are doing. You are actually registering two times, once in `onCreate()` and again in `onResume()`, each at different rates. The use of `postDelay()` just causes the data to be resent to your main thread 5 seconds later and the first time the `Runnable` runs it unregisters the listener. But at that point you'll already have 10000 events queued (based on the original code.)